# How to increment enumerates internal counter every time next(iter) called?

Tags: python

Given a iterator which may have next called in the middle of the loop I would like to be able to increment enumerates internal count from inside the loop.

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
lst_iter = iter(lst)

for index, elem in enumerate(lst_iter, start=1):
    print(index, elem)
    if elem == "b":
        print(next(enumerate(lst_iter, start=index)))
```

Outputs

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
(3, 'd')
```

I would like to update the for loops enumerated count permanently.

I can accomplish effectively the same thing with an offset.

```
offset = 0
for index, elem in enumerate(lst_iter, start=1):
    if elem == "b":
        print(next(enumerate(lst_iter, start=index)))
        offset = offset + 1
    print(index + offset, elem)
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to forgo the offset and increment enumerates internal counter every time `next` is called on the `iter`?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the desired output is? Do you just want `'b'` and `'c'` to appear in each other's places while the numbers remain in order, or do you want something else?

Comment: @FMc currently parsing stacks generated from syslog. I want to track what line the stack starts and ends at.

Comment: @Blckknght Desired output is to have each item printed in order. That's a mistake on my part.

Comment: I've been at it for a while now; and I can't wrap my head around this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to save the iterator returned by `enumerate` instead of a the iterator from `iter(lst)`. This way you can call `next` on the iterator and have the `for` loop skip over the index and value you've viewed ahead of time:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

enum_iter = enumerate(lst, start=1)

for index, elem in enum_iter:
    print(index, elem)
    if elem == "b":
        index2, elem2 = next(enum_iter)
        print(index2, elem2, "*")
```

The tuples printed by this code will be in exactly the same order as if the `if elem == "b"` block was not present, but the value after a `"b"` will have an extra suffix printed:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c *
4 d
```

Note that if your list might end with a `b` value, you should probably add some extra code to catch the `StopIteration` exception that `next` will raise.